# Literature that demonstrates organisms have a competitive advantage in numbers

Tags: ecology, ornithology, population-biology, literature, community-ecology

I'm studying two bird populations that are competing against each other for a resource: Population A and Population B.

Population A is present in much higher numbers than Population B, and as a consequence, I think that Population A has a competitive advantage over Population B.

I'm looking for literature that demonstrates that when one population is present in higher numbers than the other population, the population present in higher numbers has a competitive advantage. Can anyone point me in the direction of literature that demonstrates this?

Comment: This is not necessarily true. Take for example elephants and aphids that both feed on the same plants (competition for the same resource). It is not necessarily the case that relative quantities are linked directly to competitive advantage.

Comment: I don't see your logic that the more abundant species need to have a competitive advantage (I assume that populations A & B are referring to different species), at least without more information. There is often a negative relationship between body size and population density, and there are many other things that are affecting population abundances. Why are you assuming that competitive advantage is the key factor? Are they directly competing for the same resource? What type of resource are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

I have found these papers:
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0169534713002322

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0040580912001360

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19416834

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21930936

The last two argue that larger groups have better "problem solving" capability, and this is a clear advantage in competition.

Comment: Can you please expand your answer beyond just dropping links? This is not helpful, even if the articles might be...

Comment: He asked for papers and I gave him links to pertinent scientific publications... However, the main point is that in a larger community there is higher chance of finding solutions to problems. In case of birds, bigger is the swarm and easier will be to solve issues. This in general gives a reasonable advantage. So if two groups of the same species (or very close) are in competition the bigger group have greater chance to prevail.

Comment: Chris - answer is helpful because I asked for papers